# Different editions of Rift

Tags: rift

I've seen three different editions.

- Standard Edition
- Ashes of History Collector's Edition
- Infinity Edition

The Standard Edition is pretty self evident, but what is the difference (if any) between Ashes of History and Infinity?

***If you want all the rewards, do you have to buy them all?***

Answer (score 2):

**Infinity Edition** contains a "Generator for the Brevian Portal" which you can use to teleport to any portal in the gameworld, a Cyclone mount and a mini-pet called "Mini Regulos".

**Ashes of History Collector's Edition** contains  a special Spider Mount, a personal Banker and a faction tabard.

Source:

http://eu.riftgame.com/en/products/upgrade.php

Comment: So in order to get all of the above, one would have to buy both?